# Checking Regression Inputs & Outputs (Factor Regression)

Tags: regression, factor-models, beta

I am looking to check the assumptions and interpretation of the output of a regression that I have run for factor exposures in a long/short equity portfolio:

1. Portfolio is long/short equity with a net of 50% and a Gross of 150%
2. Regression variable are 4 long only factor indexes (Value/Quality/Momentum/Growth)
3. Using 2 years of daily return data

My regression output is the below:

[image: Regression Output]

Would i be correct in assuming the following:

1. the Coefficients could be used to represent the Beta of the portfolio to each factor
2. the growth factor is not statistically significant as a variable so thus can be removed

Is there anything further that I could improve - I am trying to reach a useful conclusion on how each factor index move will affect my portfolio?

any wisdom would be greatly appreciated (I am also constrained to do my analysis in Excel, i would have opted for python or R but not available in this case)